# How the process actually flows in branch sum python code

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

I am really sorry for asking this simple question. I am currently solving algorithms and got stuck in branch sum. I searched a lot around but nobody actually explained the actual code, just the concept. If anyone here will be kind enough to explain it to me.

```
class BinaryTree:
def __init__(self, value):
self.value = value
self.left = None
self.right = None

def branchSum(root):
    sums = []
    calculateBranchSum(root, 0, sums)
    return sums

def calculateBranchSums(node, runningSum, sums):
    if node is None:
        return
    newRunningSum = runningSum + node.value
    if node.left is None and node.right is None:
        sums.append(newRunningSum)
        return
    calculateBranchSums(node.left, newRunningSum, sums)
    calculateBranchSums(node.right, newRunningSum, sums)
```

I am mainly confused on how the node goes back? Like first with node.left, we receive the final sum. Then with node.right, newRunningSum is last sum?

Comment: Can you give an example of object that would be fed into the function? You have a recursive function here. It is using a number (`runningSum`) and a list (`sums`) to track the cumulated sums per branch. The number is used to pass the value **down** in the recursive chain, the list to pass it **up** as it is mutable.

Comment: @mozway the binary tree and array is here: https://imgur.com/a/AtGnFRZ  . i have edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node is not going back, you are just saving the result of running sum and passing that to next nodes and once you got child node(leaf node) you are appending sum and return nothing, and this sum is your branch sum

```
     1
   /  \
  2    3
  /\   /\
 4  5  6 7
```

for example, in above tree,  this is how your code flows

```
1 -> (1+2), (1+3) -> ((1+2+4), (1+2+5)),((1+3+6), (1+3+7))
```

and it reached the child node so  the sum will be added in the resultant array ie `sum_` (7,8,10, 11)  will be the final result.

so running order in this case is:

```
 1  (node)
 1+2  (node.val+node.left.val)
 1+2+4 - > (node.val + node.left.val+ node.left.left.val) save this in array
 1+2+5 ->(node.val+node.left.val+node.left.right.val) save this in array
 1+3   (node.val+node.right.val)
 1+3+6 ->(node.val+node.right.val+node.right.left.val) save this in array
 1+3+7 -> (node.val+node.right.val+node.right.right.val) save this in arry
```

Comment: "once you got child node you are returning that sum" -- you mean "leaf" node here, and _appending_ the sum, not returning it

Comment: yeah leaf node, and appending the result not reutrning it. updated

Comment: Thank you i thought the same. So, first     calculateBranchSums(node.left, newRunningSum, sums) runs right. the newRunningSum = 1+2  then     calculateBranchSums(node.right, newRunningSum, sums) runs, the newRunningSum is still 1 or its 1+2? Whats calling function within the same function called?

Comment: @NroGamerz updated solution, yes  here you have implemented pre-order traversal, ie Node-left-right

Comment: so again confused with your update. with that order how can the current code work. How the node again starts with 1?

Comment: (1+2+4) is just a order in which some is happening, after your first node ie when vlaue =1, first preorder traversal occur , ie left values are evaluated ie  `calculateBranchSums(node.left, newRunningSum, sums)` is evaluated fully and till this function vlaue of newRunningSum is 1 which is again pass to next function call  `calculateBranchSums(node.right, newRunningSum, sums)`

Comment: thank you for taking time to make me understand i will explain my question in details. So first the node is 1. then with left function, 1+2, so you mean it doesn't get out of .left function until there is no left value? So, 1+2+4. So, now finally goes to right. Which will be again 1+3+7 which i think doesn't work. Maybe its this order that will work? 1 -> (1+2), (1+3) -> ((1+2+4), (1+2+5)),((1+3+6), (1+3+7)) . like in your updated order, after 1+2+5, how the program knows to go to 1+2+5?

Comment: so it goes like this  1-> 1+2 -> 1+2+4 (left traversal over)-> 1+2 (right taversal start)-> 1+2+5 ( right travesal over) - > 1 (right traversal start) -> 1+3 -> 1+3+6 (left traversal over) - > 1+3 -> 1+3+7, now compare this traversal with the function call like how you calling revurive function where first left part is evaluated and then right part , more info you need to see how pre order traversal work and branch sum using pre order traversal in youtube